# Docker container won't start properly

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have a postgres container that I start via docker-compose (if I restart it at all). When I attempt to do this, it fails with a "can't write postmaster.pid, no space left on device" error message. Since the container never starts properly, I can't shell into the container to see what's going on with it (though given the error message, df -h is unlikely to provide any comfort).

However, the host system (Mac) has plenty of space left. Other containers continue to run fine (well, without issue... maybe they're about to blow up next).

The postgres data directory is a named volume listed in the compose yaml file.

I'm unsure how to fix this, or for that matter what has caused the problem in the first place. Where do I start in fixing this, or at least debugging the issue further?

Comment: Docker Desktop for Mac secretly runs inside a VM, and you can control its disk space through the "whale" application.  It's possible for the VM's disk to be full but still have host-system space available.

Comment: @DavidMaze What's in the VM disk that has filled everything up? Is it just a crapload of ancient log files? I've made no real changes recently.

Comment: Images, container-local filesystems, named volumes, probably the actual content of your database.

Comment: @David Maze The content of my database (as of a couple of months ago) didn't exceed 50mb. I doubt that it's the problem.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks, you helped get me going in the right direction with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VM itself has a default max size of about 60gb. It's located at

```
~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/Docker.qcow2
```

Additionally, if you have many dangling volumes (those unused by any container), these can be a problem. They likely are partly or wholly responsible for this. The `docker system prune` command apparently doesn't get rid of these (at least by default). You can check if there are many with this command

```
docker volume ls -qf dangling=true
```

Take careful note of the list if it's long, some may show here simply because the containers have been stopped. To remove them, you can use this command (this may be old, but it works, feel free to edit in a better one)

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true)
```

Also note that if you want to filter items out of the list (so that they aren't removed), you can do so inside the parentheses like so

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | grep -v somestring)
```

After doing so (it takes a few minutes), you may see a reduction in the size of the qcow file, and the containers may restart without error. I personally only picked up about 5% disk free afterwards, which may mean that I'm about to run into the issue again in a few weeks or months. Not sure what I'll do then.